# start fragment from different class, not activity class

Tags: android, class, fragment

I have a Fragment_main that needs to access a class to check if logged in or not.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment__main, container, false);

        session = new SessionManager(getContext());

        session.valida();
}
```

In session.valida(), check if true or false.

```
public void valida(){

    if(valida){
        Open fragment_login
    }
    else
    {
        open fragment_main
    }
}
```

If true open fragment_login, if false open fragment_main.

I used many intents, and fragment managers to start, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just construct a `FragmentManager` and use it. You need to call `getFragmentManager()` in your fragment or activity and pass it into the `SessionManager`.

Answer (score 0):

let me get this

```
if (valid) {
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
else{
    LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I have helped

Comment: Dont work, show this error:04-13 20:26:47.521: E/AndroidRuntime(32655): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.jdnetservices.pcm/br.com.jdnetservices.pcm.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentManager android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager()' on a null object reference

Comment: If you are using appcompact try this  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This is activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in YourNameFragment.class

```
 if(valida){
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, new OpenFragment())
            .commit();
}
else
{
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
}
```